# Question re. potential nearest neighbors and hyper-rectangles

Tags: statistics

I am confused over the following definition and proposition of *k Potential Nearest Neighbors* found in [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1198/016214505000001230?needAccess=true). Here are the relevant definitions (see  pictures below):

Fix a set of sample points $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\} \subseteq \mathbf{R}^d$.

**Definition.** A metric is a *monotone distance measure* if it satisfies the property that, for any two points **a** and **b**  in the space and any point **c** belonging to the hyperrectangle spanned by **a** and **b**, the distance from **c** is closer to **a** than **b** is.

**Definition.** A point $x_i$ is a $k$-PNN of $x_0$ if there exists a monotone distance measure under which $x_i$ is among the $k$ closest to $x_0$ among all the sample points.

The article claims that the following proposition is obvious:

**Proposition.** A sample point $x_i$ is a $k$-PNN of $x_0$ if and only if there are fewer than $k$ sample points other than $x_i$ in the hyperrectangle defined by $x_0$ and $x_i$ (i.e. having $x_0$ and $x_i$ as opposing vertices).

---

> I am having doubts on how to prove this proposition. Could someone give me a pointer?

---

Here's a an example illustrating my confusion. Consider the following setup: take $d = 1$, and $x_0 = 0$ for simplicity. If the sample points are $\{-1, 2\}$ , then both are $1$-PNN's (the hyperrectangles being intervals in this case).

Then under what metric would $2$ be closer to $0$ than $-1$? In fact, $2$ would remain a 1-PNN for the sample points $\{-1, -{1 \over 2}, \dots, -{1 \over L}, 2\}$ for any value of $L$, which would seem to indicate that the metric would need to have some sort of a "directional bias" which is in contradiction to the symmetric property of a metric.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the symmetry property of a metric. A metric is symmetric with respect to two points, that is, $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$. That doesn’t imply that the metric is symmetric with respect to some global geometric transformation.

In your example, a metric that makes $2$ a nearest neighbour and is a monotone distance measure is $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ with

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
3x&x\le0\;,\\
x&x\gt0\;.
\end{cases}
$$